# i want to check whether the firefox window is active for a time or idle

Tags: javascript, firefox, state, browser-state

i want to check whether the Firefox window is active for a time or idle. The below mentioned code is working in chrome window. but not in Firefox.

```
chrome.idle.queryState(20000, function (state) {
            console.log(state);
             if (state === "idle") {
    }
    });
```

Comment: Which version of firefox are you using? https://caniuse.com/#search=idle

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by checking `visibilitychange` event on the current window,

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
```

Also Check Page Visibility API on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)

Note:

Current browser support:

- Chrome 13+
- Internet Explorer 10+
- Firefox 10+
- Opera 12.10+ [read notes]

Comment: i don't want to trigger something when tab change. i just want to check the firefox browser current state and the code that i mentioned is working in chrome as expected.